# Javascript Date returns wrong time

Tags: javascript, date

I am having a date which server returns in ISO-8601 is **2019-04-17T10:20:32**

I had passed this Date timestamp to javascript new Date(2019-04-17T10:20:32) -> which return **Apr 17, 2019, 3:20:34 PM**.

What could be the reason for this ? Does it uses the local time zone(I doubt this because it happens  only on few systems) ?

The client system had using **PST** time zone where as server system uses **Abu Dhabi, Muscat**

Note: client uses Windows XP( not sure, this can be a reason)

//JS/typescript code

```
entryTime = new Date(item.entryTime);
```

//html code

```
{{entryTime | date :'medium'}}
```

Comment: one word ... timezone ... what timezone is the server giving you?

Comment: (UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat

Comment: so, the server is giving you Abu Dhabi time ... are you in Abu Dhabi time?

Comment: No, the issue was in client using Pacific Standard Time.. I want to know the reason why this difference

Comment: because Abu Dhabi is not in the Pacific? I think there's more to this ... please show the browser code you use to create the object and display it

Comment: entryTime = new Date(item.entryTime);

Comment: even I changed the system timezone to Abudhabi still gives wrong time

Comment: yes, working with timezones is a pain

Comment: what is your expected o/p ?you can convert it

Comment: @JaromandaX—the timestamp doesn't have a timezone, so it should be treated as local and show the same local time (10:20:32) regardless of the host timezone.

Comment: Yes. It should. But without seeing code who knows what the op is doing